# Page files in Linux

Tags: virtual-memory

What is page file in Linux? There is any connection between page file and paging?

Answer (score 3):

A *page file* is the Windows term for what is called a *swap file* in the Linux world (and more generally in the Unix world). Linux tends to use swap partitions rather than swap files, but supports both.

In modern usage, “swapping” and “paging” are synonyms. Historically “swapping” started out as meaning replacing the (single) application in memory with another one and keeping the memory of the inactive applications on disk, and “paging” started out as meaning moving individual memory pages between disk and main memory. But since the 1970s, “swapping” is commonly used for “paging”, and the word “paging” isn't used much in the Unix world.

If the interviewer used this word, either they are very unfamiliar with Linux or they were testing to see if you are familiar with both Linux and Windows.